# Python: If happy_with_character == 'NO' The next area of code begins. How can i fix this? [Answer/Archive]

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
while character_creation == True:
    Class = str.upper(input("Which class do you want to play?"))
    if Class == 'ASSASSIN':
        print("""You are an Assassin.
Your abilities are:""", assassin_abilities)
        character_creation = False
    elif Class == 'ARCHER':
        print("""You are an Archer.
Your abilities are:""", archer_abilities)
        character_creation = False
    elif Class == 'BARBARIAN':
        print("""You are a Barbarian.
Your abilities are:""", barbarian_abilities)
        character_creation = False
    elif Class == 'MAGE':
        print("""You are a Mage.
Your abilities are:""", mage_abilities)
        character_creation = False
    else:
        print("This is an invalid option, please try again.")
        character_creation = True
name = input("What would you like to name your character?")
print("Your character is now called", name.title()) #.title() makes first     
letter of each word in a string capital   .capitalize() makes first letter 
of the first word a capital
happy_with_character = str.upper(input("Are you happy with your     
character?"))
if happy_with_character == 'YES':
    character_creation = False
    print("Lets Begin")
elif happy_with_character == 'NO':
    character_creation = True

#Game starts here
import time         #Makes time a factor
print("Darkness...")
```

I am trying to make a text-based DND style game and want:

```
if happy_with_character == 'YES':
    character_creation = False
    print("Lets Begin")
elif happy_with_character == 'NO':
    character_creation = True
```

To work so that `character_creation` only repeats if the answer to 
`happy_with_character` is `'NO'`. But i have tried multiple ways that i know of and none of them worked.
What should I change/add/indent?

I'm almost 100% self taught will only the extreme basics being taught to me in school. I get some help from my teachers with small problems.

thanks! :)

Comment: You aren't assigning to `character_creation`; you are comparing its current value to a Boolean literal. You want `=`, not `==`.

Comment: @chepner in which part are we talking about?

Comment: It should be `if happy_with_character == 'YES': character_creation = False`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you! But my original problem still stands

Comment: Please provide a *minimal* example that demonstrates your problem. There is far too much code in your question.

Comment: @chepner I have done that for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the character creation a function, and only move on from that when the answer is 'YES', this should work for you:

```
#Character Creation
def createCharacter():
    character_creation = True
    while character_creation == True:
        Class = str.upper(input("Which class do you want to play?"))
        if Class == 'ASSASSIN':
            print("You are an Assassin. Your abilities are:", assassin_abilities)
            character_creation = False
        elif Class == 'ARCHER':
            print("You are an Archer. Your abilities are:", archer_abilities)
            character_creation = False
        elif Class == 'BARBARIAN':
            print("You are a Barbarian. Your abilities are:", barbarian_abilities)
            character_creation = False
        elif Class == 'MAGE':
            print("You are a Mage. Your abilities are:", mage_abilities)
            character_creation = False
        else:
            print("This is an invalid option, please try again.")
            character_creation = True
    name = input("What would you like to name your character?")
    print("Your character is now called", name.title()) #.title() makes first letter of each word in a string capital   .capitalize() makes first letter of the first word a capital

createCharacter()
happy_with_character = ""
while happy_with_character != 'YES' and happy_with_character != 'NO':
    happy_with_character = str.upper(input("Are you happy with your     
character?"))
    if happy_with_character == 'NO':
        createCharacter()
```

For these purposes, this should make using the character_creation bool unnecessary outside the createCharacter() function.

Comment: thank you. i have just tried this but my original problem still stands.

Comment: Where would i add this and what would i remove?

Comment: This would replace everything above "#Game starts here" in the current edit of the code you have in the question.

Comment: `name = input("What would you like to name your character?")`

Comment: This line show an error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Now when i type anything that isnt one of the classes it continues to ask what to name the character

Comment: Edited again to leave your original while loop in. My bad, you didn't need that bool for the first part of your question but I missed the part where you used it to validate class.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Choice game.py", line 79, in <module>
    createCharacter()
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Choice game.py", line 59, in createCharacter
    while character_creation == True:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'character_creation' referenced before assignment

Comment: Edited again to declare character_creation = True before the while loop. Despite no upvote and countless edits, I hope this has been helpful.

Comment: Omg! Thanks it worked. This has helped me to begin to learn the def function. And I would love to up vote this but I don't have enough reputation to do it. I'm really sorry.

Comment: Sadly, 15 reputation is needed and I do not really know how to get more reputation.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = input("What would you like to name your character?")
print("Your character is now called", name.title()) #.title() makes first letter of each word in a string capital   .capitalize() makes first letter of the first word a capital
happy_with_character = str.upper(input("Are you happy with your character?"))
if happy_with_character == 'YES':
    character_creation = False
    print("Lets Begin")
elif happy_with_character == 'NO':
    character_creation = True
```

This section of your code needs to be indented to fall within your `while` loop.

Comment: It is in-line isnt it?

Comment: As your code currently stands, it's outside the while loop. But, you *only* want to exit the while loop if `happy_with_character` is YES.

Answer (score 0):

use functions!

```
def ask_yes_no(prompt):
    while True: # keep asking until they enter yes or no!
        result = input(prompt)
        if result.lower()[0] == "y":
           return True # they said yes!
        if result.lower()[0] == "n":
           return False # they said no!
        print("Error: please enter yes or no!")

def create_character():
    #get all your character stats here
    if not ask_yes_no("Are you happy with your character?"):
       return create_character() # they said no, so lets try and recreate it
    else:
        return character_data  # they said yes!



character = create_character()
```

Comment: what part is confusing? ... try reading it outloud ... the comments should help clarify any confusion

Comment: Its just a general i dont know the def function or why there is () after character_create. i have not learnt this and thats making it sound confusing